# Group by date and count specific values

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, sum

I'm trying to create a report where there is only one row for each date, and then a separate counter for each color that the customers has chosen.

The input data consists of two columns, one for date, and one for color. like this:

```
2014-04-11  BLUE

2014-04-11  GREEN

2014-04-11  BLUE

2014-04-10  RED

2014-04-10  GREEN

2014-04-09  RED

2014-04-09  RED
```

This is what i would like the report to look like:

```
| DATE | BLUE | GREEN | RED |

| 2014-04-11 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

| 2014-04-10 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

| 2014-04-09 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
```

I guess I need to group it by date, but the problem is that I cannot "sum" or "count" only BLUE colors etc. Is this even possible? If so, can someone please help me?

Comment: do you have any other values of color other than the three?

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
select 
    "date",
    SUM(case when color='BLUE' then 1 else 0 end) as BLUE,
    SUM(case when color='GREEN' then 1 else 0 end) as GREEN,
    SUM(case when color='RED' then 1 else 0 end) as RED
from
    YourTable
Group by "date"
```

Comment: This is exacly what I needed! You are the best! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "DATE",
        SUM(CASE WHEN color='GREEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as GREEN
        SUM(CASE WHEN color='RED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as RED
        SUM(CASE WHEN color='BLUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BLUE
FROM tableName
GROUP BY "DATE"
```

You need to escape column named DATE with double qouotes as it is a keyword in Oracle